# DFTB+ parameters for additional atoms

Tags: computational-chemistry, dftb-plus

I wonder if anyone here knows about additional atomic parameters and interactions sets for atoms not currently present in the DFTB parameter sets. The parameter sets are located at [DFTB parameters](https://dftb.org/parameters/download). For example, I am interested in simulating systems that contain tetrafluoroborate anion, FB-(F)F. However, I have not across B-F interaction sets. Is anybody aware of a parametrization procedure to add new atomic interaction pairs to DFTB, or if any proprietary software already includes parameters beyond those provided at the link.

Thank you,

Comment: have you tried to ask the DFTB+ mailing list? They might know about unpublished parameter sets.

Comment: Thanks, @Greg, I have sent a question to that list as well.

Comment: @bhopshang did you get an answer there?

Comment: It's more of a comment – than an answer. I was hoping to get more clarification. However, I genuinely understand if the question needs to be closed for management purposes.

Comment: @bhopshang I didn't see your response because you didn't ping me using the @ character. Are you able to provide us a link to the conversation that occurred at the DFTB+ mailing list?